# Windows 8.1 will not boot up and I want to move all of my files

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, boot-manager

My Windows 8.1 laptop will not boot up in normal or safe mode. This has been happening recently. Is there a program I can use to take all of my files from my primary hard drive and move them to my 2nd one so I can do a fresh install of windows on the primary drive? If so, what is the program(es) called and where can I get it?

Comment: You don't need any special software.  You just need a working OS.  If you have a working OS just copy and paste the files to your secondary HDD.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from your Windows DVD and use the System Recovery Console to copy files from your hard drive to a USB drive or a secondary Hard Drive.

1. Connect a USB Hard drive or other storage drive to your computer that is large enough to hold all of the files you want to copy.
2. Start your computer and boot from your Windows DVD (it will take some time to load files)
3. When prompted, choose your language, time format, and keyboard, and then click **Next**.
4. In the lower, left-hand corner, click **Repair your computer**
5. Click **Troubleshoot**, click **Advanced Options**, and then click **Command Prompt**

From this Command Prompt, you can use standard **cd**, **dir**,**xcopy**, and **copy** commands to navigate your hard drive and copy all the files you want to your attached USB storage device.